# Changing my web browser font

Tags: linux, fonts, chromium, gnome3

I just installed OpenSUSE 13.2 on my system with GNOME Shell. The font that I get is just plain hideous. I'm not talking about the title bar font though. I'm talking about this monstrosity that I see in Chromium:

[image]

Do you see what I mean? The font is hideous. It's thin, it's not anti-aliased at all, and small text is impossible to read without zooming in. There has to be a way to change that, right? We're talking about Linux here...

Comment: Have you tried to change it through web browser's settings?

Comment: @ElvinAslanov Yes, that only works for some pages though. The tabs still have the same hideous font.

Answer (score 1):

If the tab headings themselves have a poor font then it's probably relying on system fonts.

You can change them here: Computer->Control Center->Look and Feel->Appearance

The Gnome shell font can also be edited via a css file found here: /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css

more info: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_openSUSE_Desktop_Fonts